I am trying to use the subfigures to plot the figures with the common figure number
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{45mm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_x_state.png}
        \caption{(a)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF x state.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_y_state.png}
        \caption{(b)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF y state.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_obj_fun.png}
        \caption{(c)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF known objective function.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_traj.png}
        \caption{(d)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF trajectory.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_HPF.png}
        \caption{(e)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF HPF.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle_sim_without_GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_control input.png}
        \caption{(f)}
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF control input.}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Simulation results of unicycle dynamics using a known mathematical expression of the objective function to access the measurements: (a) x state, (b) y state, (c) Objective function (d) Planar trajectory of the system, the initial position is depicted by "star" sign, and the extremum position represented by "stop" sign, (e) HPF, and (f) Linear velocity.}
    \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle dynamics without GEKF simulation results}
\end{figure}

I am using the above code to add the figures, but figures are not aligning properly, and each figure has its own figure number, but I want all the figures should a common figure number with caption "Simulation results of unicycle dynamics using a known mathematical expression of the objective function to access the measurements: (a) x state, (b) y state, (c) Objective function (d) Planar trajectory of the system, the initial position is depicted by "star" sign, and the extremum position represented by "stop" sign, (e) HPF, and (f) Linear velocity."
Please help me asap.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Plwase, extend your code frament to com,plewte small document,which we can compile as it is. So far we can obly gues, how your document preamble looks like, i.e. which (to your problem relevant) packge you use for your figures setings

Just guessing ... Are you after something like this?

Above image is generated by following MWE (Minimal Working Example}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}        

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}         % <---  added
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_x_state}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF x state.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_y_state}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF y state.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_obj_fun}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF known objective function.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_traj}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF trajectory.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_HPF}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF HPF.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Figures/Chapter4/Simulation Results/Unicycle sim without GEKF/chapter4_unicycle_sim_control input}
        \caption{}                      % <---  changed
        \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle simulation without GEKF control input.}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Simulation results of unicycle dynamics using a known mathematical expression of the objective function to access the measurements: (a) x state, (b) y state, (c) Objective function (d) Planar trajectory of the system, the initial position is depicted by "star" sign, and the extremum position represented by "stop" sign, (e) HPF, and (f) Linear velocity.}
    \label{fig: chapter 4 unicycle dynamics without GEKF simulation results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

As you can se, in above MWE are in comparison to your code fragment made two changes:

in subfigure are replaced \caption{(...)} width `\caption{}˙. By this below subfigures are only one, correct labels
since all images have the same width, I define common width for images by defineng them by key Gin


Hi, thank you for your response, but still it is not working.

@shivambajpai, what not working? What error you got?  If you tested my MWE as it is, you should got the same result as I show in answer.
